# выводится пустая веб страница

Tags: php

Этот код правильно выводит данные из удалённого сервера:

```
  <?php
$host="localhost";
$user="***";
$password="***";
$db_name="***";

$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name);

 $sql="select * from goods";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
       echo $row["goods_id"]." ".$row["goods_name"]; 
       echo "<br>";
   }

mysqli_close($conn);

// header(string "Location:index.php");

?>
```

а этот код выводит пустую веб страницу :

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="***";
$password="***";
$db_name="***";

$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db_name);

 $sql="select * from goods";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 echo <table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>Goods_id</th>
 <th>Goods_name</th>
 </tr>;

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$row["goods_id"]."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row["goods_name"]."</td>"; 
       echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);

// header(string "Location:index.php");

?>
```

Не могу найти причину. Прошу помощи.

Comment: первое echo без кавычек у вас, надо заключить в кавычки "<table border='1'....";

Comment: А также конструкция `echo` поддерживает оператор `and so on` - и так далее: `echo 'str1', 'str2', 'str3';` - передача аргументов через запятую. Работает быстрее, чем конкатенация строк.

Comment: @And есть пруф на эту тему? Может в PHP есть оптимизация в рантайме на это этот счет и они одинаковое кол-во тактов занимают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из-за отсутствия кавычек у строки после echo у вас ошибка, которая не выводится на экран. Вам нужно как минимум исправить ошибку:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // настраиваем уровень ошибок
ini_set('display_errors', true); // включаем вывод ошибок на экран

$host = "localhost";
$user = "***";
$password = "***";
$db_name = "***";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);

$sql = "select * from goods";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Goods_id</th>
<th>Goods_name</th>
</tr>";

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row["goods_id"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row["goods_name"] . "</td>"; 
       echo "</tr>";
   }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Так же добавил в начале кода две строки для регулирования уровня ошибок и показ их на экране, желательно для этого конфиг поменять, но можно и момент исполнения кода это делать, правда придется это делать во всех файлах, которые запускаются.

P.S. Так же рекомендую сразу приучать себя для работы с базой использовать [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

P.P.S. Заметил строчку в конце кода с выводом заголовка `header(string "Location:index.php");`. Всегда отправляйте заголовки **до вывода на экран** любой информации, например через `echo`.